# Best answers, should I always pick most relevant or helpful to the specific question, or can I pick the one that's most valuable?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159763/excel-udf-weighted-randbetween) about a bug in some code I wrote. I essentially asked for the community to look through it and find the problem, my question was of the *'What's wrong with this?'* type.

However the answers I received gave workarounds; other ways to solve the problem that my faulty code attempted to tackle. Technically these don't answer my question as I stated it. Soon after I discovered what the problem was and posted it as an answer.

That left me with a dilemma; should I

- accept my own answer as the most helpful in solving my problem (if anyone happens to have *precisely* the same issue as me, I think I explain how to solve it. And to be perfectly honest the other answers I received *did not*  help me solve the problem)

or do I

- pick the answer that I deem most valuable, even if it does not answer my specific question

I've glanced through the Help documentation but couldn't find what I was looking for there. The general impression I got though was that option 1 was what the 'best answer' tick is designed for. Here's what I've found* ...

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
> statement indicating that the question has now been answered
> perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that
> worked for him or her personally**, but not every user comes back to
> accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the
> accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

... which I take to mean 2 things. First, as I've said, the accepted answer should be specific to solving your problem. Second, the accepted answer should not influence how another user might rank the solutions; i.e. provided that user has read and/or appreciates this aspect of the help documentation, then they should know that it doesn't matter which answer **I** accept, they should consider all solutions independently.

However I feel that this interpretation is in conflict with that fundamental principle of Stack Overflow, that we're trying to build up a database of knowledge. As a novice troubleshooting my program, I'd (personally) much rather I find answers to a question that demonstrate general principles rather than the highly specific case. In many instances it's likely the circumstances surrounding the problem will not be identical to what's available online - so a more general answer is required.

Sure, regardless of which answer I pick as best, the other answers are there if you scroll down. But I worry a user coming in from a Google search may not appreciate the green tick's significance as *opinion* not *fact* when you are picking out a 'best' solution. - i.e. they might think the green tick denotes the objectively *best approach* to a general problem, not the most helpful approach to a specific (not that it can't denote both, but as in my example I don't think it *necessarily* will).

So in this case, as in others, should I pick best answer based on the absolute most helpful answer to solve the specific problem, or can we use the green tick to promote valuable and worthwhile content? (obviously upvoting *helps*, but to a off-site visitor that green tick is the first indicator they'll see of a possible answer to their question)

**(emphasis my own)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are free to accept whatever you want.

Now, do consider future visitors: why might they find your question, what keywords are they looking for and what problem are they most likely trying to solve that brought them to your question? Now, is the answer that most literally answers the question more useful, or would it be more useful to make them aware of some fundamental problem in their approach and steer them towards a different approach? In other words: how wrong was the original approach, is it more important to correct it at the root, or are those workarounds nice to know but the problem can ultimately be solved in a straight forward manner.